# UPS Rates API - how to get service description

Tags: rate, ups

I am building a shipping rates calculator and I need the service code, description and price from the API response. I have noticed that I never get a response for:
/RatingServiceSelectionResponse/RatedShipment/Service/Description - but I get a response for the price and service code.

I contacted support about this and they said:

> " Unfortunately, the description for the service (inside of the response) is only available in our Time in Transit API"

This seems very strange to have an Rates API that does not provide the service descriptions, it seems a bit useless without this info.

Does anyone know if there any way to do a lookup for the service description using the service code that is brought back from the Rates API?

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*The codes are found in Appendix E of the Rating Package Web Services Developers Guide*.

I've had similar frustration with the UPS API's.
You're right - the ...Service/Description is blank in the Rate service's response. So, you have to go with the ...Service/Code value and write your own code-description map based on those codes.

For example, here are the values I mapped out in a Perl script:

```
%ups_service_code   = (
    '01'    => 'UPS Next Day Air',
    '02'    => 'UPS 2nd Day Air',
    '03'    => 'UPS Ground',
    '07'    => 'UPS Worldwide Express',
    '08'    => 'UPS Worldwide Expedited',
    '11'    => 'UPS Standard',
    '12'    => 'UPS 3 Day Select',
    '13'    => 'UPS Next Day Air Saver',
    '14'    => 'UPS Next Day Air Early A.M.',
    '54'    => 'UPS Worldwide Express Plus',
    '59'    => 'UPS 2nd Day Air A.M.',
    '65'    => 'UPS Saver',
    ## 82-86 are Polish Domestic Shipments
    '82'    => 'UPS Today Standard',
    '83'    => 'UPS Today Dedicated Courier',
    '84'    => 'UPS Today Intercity',
    '85'    => 'UPS Today Express',
    '86'    => 'UPS Today Express Saver'
);
```

Now, what's REALLY frustrating is that when you implement the TimeInTransit (TNT) service, you find that it returns the descriptions but no codes!
But what I found is that the descriptions returned by the TNT service match the descriptions of the Rate codes from the developer guide (in example above). So, that's the way I've ended up matching TNT data with Rate data.

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE:**
For TransitInTime request you can find the codes in the *Time in Transit documentation* look at the end of the PDF section "Service Codes". 
This codes anyway are different from the ones used in the rate so you have to create another map for that.

This is an example

```
/* Mapping for destination within the origin country */
        $SCmappings = array(
            '23' => '54',   /* UPS Express Plus                     */
            '24' => '07',   /* UPS Express                          */
            '25' => '11',   /* UPS Standard                         */
            '26' => '65',   /* UPS Express Saver                    */
            '39' => '70'    /* UPS Access Point Economy             */
        );

        /* Mapping for destination within the European Union */
        $EUmappings = array(
            '08' => '11',   /* UPS Standard                         */
            '10' => '07',   /* UPS Express                          */
            '18' => '65',   /* UPS Express Saver                    */
            '22' => '54',   /* UPS Express Plus                     */
            '29' => '08',   /* UPS Express Freight - UPS Expedited  */
            '39' => '70'    /* UPS Access Point Economy             */
        );

        /* Mapping for destination outside the European Union */
        $nonEUmappings = array(
            '01' => '07',   /* UPS Worldwide Express                */
            '05' => '08',   /* UPS Worldwide Expedited              */
          //  '11' => '???',   /* UPS Express NA 1                     */
            '21' => '54',   /* UPS Worldwide Express Plus           */
            '28' => '65',   /* UPS Worldwide Express Saver          */
            '29' => '11',   /* UPS Express Freight - UPS Standard   */
            '39' => '70'    /* UPS Access Point Economy             */
        );
```

Comment: yes Ive seen the list in Appendix E but couldn't figure it out as it has multiple services for code 7.  ie.  UPS Express, UPS Worldwide ExpressSM (for US)  and UPS Worldwide ExpressSM (for Peuto Rico).  Its confusing and Im not sure how to select the correct one programmatically.

Comment: Just copy/paste my descriptions from above, where the RATE service code is mapped to the appropriate description. Then _ignore_ the code returned by the Time In Transit service (TNT), and in stead select the TNT description to match against the descriptions above.

Comment: Im not using the TNT service and so thats not an issue for me, Im still unclear how you have "UPS Worldwide Express" for code 7 when in the documentation there are two other descriptions for code 7 also.

Comment: Appendix E (pg 92 of the web services guide) only uses 2 descriptions with code 07: UPS Express, and UPS Worldwide Express. From what I gather, these are the same basic service - they just call it "UPS Worldwide Express" when the origin is outside the US and PR. (My codes above are being used for shipments originating in the US). So it's up to you to know which country your origin address is in, and apply the appropriate description. UPS could have made this a lot easier by simply providing a code description in the web service response.

Comment: I will need to add another column for the shipping from country so I can select the correct one.  thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for this, very strange that the service codes in TNT arent the same ones as in the Rate API. Still applies in 2018.

Answer (score 1):

This is how Magento maps the UPS code.

```
public function getCode($type, $code='')
    {
        $codes = array(
            'action'=>array(
                'single'=>'3',
                'all'=>'4',
            ),

            'originShipment'=>array(
                // United States Domestic Shipments
                'United States Domestic Shipments' => array(
                    '01' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Next Day Air'),
                    '02' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Second Day Air'),
                    '03' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Ground'),
                    '07' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Worldwide Express'),
                    '08' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Worldwide Expedited'),
                    '11' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Standard'),
                    '12' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Three-Day Select'),
                    '13' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Next Day Air Saver'),
                    '14' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Next Day Air Early A.M.'),
                    '54' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Worldwide Express Plus'),
                    '59' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Second Day Air A.M.'),
                    '65' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Saver'),
                ),
                // Shipments Originating in United States
                'Shipments Originating in United States' => array(
                    '01' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Next Day Air'),
                    '02' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Second Day Air'),
                    '03' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Ground'),
                    '07' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Worldwide Express'),
                    '08' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Worldwide Expedited'),
                    '11' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Standard'),
                    '12' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Three-Day Select'),
                    '14' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Next Day Air Early A.M.'),
                    '54' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Worldwide Express Plus'),
                    '59' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Second Day Air A.M.'),
                    '65' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Worldwide Saver'),
                ),
                // Shipments Originating in Canada
                'Shipments Originating in Canada' => array(
                    '01' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Express'),
                    '02' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Expedited'),
                    '07' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Worldwide Express'),
                    '08' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Worldwide Expedited'),
                    '11' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Standard'),
                    '12' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Three-Day Select'),
                    '14' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Express Early A.M.'),
                    '65' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Saver'),
                ),
                // Shipments Originating in the European Union
                'Shipments Originating in the European Union' => array(
                    '07' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Express'),
                    '08' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Expedited'),
                    '11' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Standard'),
                    '54' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Worldwide Express PlusSM'),
                    '65' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Saver'),
                ),
                // Polish Domestic Shipments
                'Polish Domestic Shipments' => array(
                    '07' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Express'),
                    '08' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Expedited'),
                    '11' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Standard'),
                    '54' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Worldwide Express Plus'),
                    '65' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Saver'),
                    '82' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Today Standard'),
                    '83' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Today Dedicated Courrier'),
                    '84' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Today Intercity'),
                    '85' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Today Express'),
                    '86' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Today Express Saver'),
                ),
                // Puerto Rico Origin
                'Puerto Rico Origin' => array(
                    '01' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Next Day Air'),
                    '02' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Second Day Air'),
                    '03' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Ground'),
                    '07' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Worldwide Express'),
                    '08' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Worldwide Expedited'),
                    '14' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Next Day Air Early A.M.'),
                    '54' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Worldwide Express Plus'),
                    '65' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Saver'),
                ),
                // Shipments Originating in Mexico
                'Shipments Originating in Mexico' => array(
                    '07' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Express'),
                    '08' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Expedited'),
                    '54' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Express Plus'),
                    '65' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Saver'),
                ),
                // Shipments Originating in Other Countries
                'Shipments Originating in Other Countries' => array(
                    '07' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Express'),
                    '08' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Worldwide Expedited'),
                    '11' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Standard'),
                    '54' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Worldwide Express Plus'),
                    '65' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Saver')
                )
            ),

            'method'=>array(
                '1DM'    => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Next Day Air Early AM'),
                '1DML'   => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Next Day Air Early AM Letter'),
                '1DA'    => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Next Day Air'),
                '1DAL'   => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Next Day Air Letter'),
                '1DAPI'  => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Next Day Air Intra (Puerto Rico)'),
                '1DP'    => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Next Day Air Saver'),
                '1DPL'   => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Next Day Air Saver Letter'),
                '2DM'    => Mage::helper('usa')->__('2nd Day Air AM'),
                '2DML'   => Mage::helper('usa')->__('2nd Day Air AM Letter'),
                '2DA'    => Mage::helper('usa')->__('2nd Day Air'),
                '2DAL'   => Mage::helper('usa')->__('2nd Day Air Letter'),
                '3DS'    => Mage::helper('usa')->__('3 Day Select'),
                'GND'    => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Ground'),
                'GNDCOM' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Ground Commercial'),
                'GNDRES' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Ground Residential'),
                'STD'    => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Canada Standard'),
                'XPR'    => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Worldwide Express'),
                'WXS'    => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Worldwide Express Saver'),
                'XPRL'   => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Worldwide Express Letter'),
                'XDM'    => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Worldwide Express Plus'),
                'XDML'   => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Worldwide Express Plus Letter'),
                'XPD'    => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Worldwide Expedited'),
            ),

            'pickup'=>array(
                'RDP'    => array("label"=>'Regular Daily Pickup',"code"=>"01"),
                'OCA'    => array("label"=>'On Call Air',"code"=>"07"),
                'OTP'    => array("label"=>'One Time Pickup',"code"=>"06"),
                'LC'     => array("label"=>'Letter Center',"code"=>"19"),
                'CC'     => array("label"=>'Customer Counter',"code"=>"03"),
            ),

            'container'=>array(
                'CP'     => '00', // Customer Packaging
                'ULE'    => '01', // UPS Letter Envelope
                'CSP'    => '02', // Customer Supplied Package
                'UT'     => '03', // UPS Tube
                'PAK'    => '04', // PAK
                'UEB'    => '21', // UPS Express Box
                'UW25'   => '24', // UPS Worldwide 25 kilo
                'UW10'   => '25', // UPS Worldwide 10 kilo
                'PLT'    => '30', // Pallet
                'SEB'    => '2a', // Small Express Box
                'MEB'    => '2b', // Medium Express Box
                'LEB'    => '2c', // Large Express Box
            ),

            'container_description'=>array(
                'CP'     => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Customer Packaging'),
                'ULE'    => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Letter Envelope'),
                'CSP'    => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Customer Supplied Package'),
                'UT'     => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Tube'),
                'PAK'    => Mage::helper('usa')->__('PAK'),
                'UEB'    => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Express Box'),
                'UW25'   => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Worldwide 25 kilo'),
                'UW10'   => Mage::helper('usa')->__('UPS Worldwide 10 kilo'),
                'PLT'    => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Pallet'),
                'SEB'    => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Small Express Box'),
                'MEB'    => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Medium Express Box'),
                'LEB'    => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Large Express Box'),
            ),

            'dest_type'=>array(
                'RES'    => '01', // Residential
                'COM'    => '02', // Commercial
            ),

            'dest_type_description'=>array(
                'RES'    => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Residential'),
                'COM'    => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Commercial'),
            ),

            'unit_of_measure'=>array(
                'LBS'   =>  Mage::helper('usa')->__('Pounds'),
                'KGS'   =>  Mage::helper('usa')->__('Kilograms'),
            ),
            'containers_filter' => array(
                array(
                    'containers' => array('00'), // Customer Packaging
                    'filters'    => array(
                        'within_us' => array(
                            'method' => array(
                                '01', // Next Day Air
                                '13', // Next Day Air Saver
                                '12', // 3 Day Select
                                '59', // 2nd Day Air AM
                                '03', // Ground
                                '14', // Next Day Air Early AM
                                '02', // 2nd Day Air
                            )
                        ),
                        'from_us' => array(
                            'method' => array(
                                '07', // Worldwide Express
                                '54', // Worldwide Express Plus
                                '08', // Worldwide Expedited
                                '65', // Worldwide Saver
                                '11', // Standard
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    // Small Express Box, Medium Express Box, Large Express Box, UPS Tube
                    'containers' => array('2a', '2b', '2c', '03'),
                    'filters'    => array(
                        'within_us' => array(
                            'method' => array(
                                '01', // Next Day Air
                                '13', // Next Day Air Saver
                                '14', // Next Day Air Early AM
                                '02', // 2nd Day Air
                                '59', // 2nd Day Air AM
                                '13', // Next Day Air Saver
                            )
                        ),
                        'from_us' => array(
                            'method' => array(
                                '07', // Worldwide Express
                                '54', // Worldwide Express Plus
                                '08', // Worldwide Expedited
                                '65', // Worldwide Saver
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'containers' => array('24', '25'), // UPS Worldwide 25 kilo, UPS Worldwide 10 kilo
                    'filters'    => array(
                        'within_us' => array(
                            'method' => array()
                        ),
                        'from_us' => array(
                            'method' => array(
                                '07', // Worldwide Express
                                '54', // Worldwide Express Plus
                                '65', // Worldwide Saver
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'containers' => array('01', '04'), // UPS Letter, UPS PAK
                    'filters'    => array(
                        'within_us' => array(
                            'method' => array(
                                '01', // Next Day Air
                                '14', // Next Day Air Early AM
                                '02', // 2nd Day Air
                                '59', // 2nd Day Air AM
                                '13', // Next Day Air Saver
                            )
                        ),
                        'from_us' => array(
                            'method' => array(
                                '07', // Worldwide Express
                                '54', // Worldwide Express Plus
                                '65', // Worldwide Saver
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'containers' => array('04'), // UPS PAK
                    'filters'    => array(
                        'within_us' => array(
                            'method' => array()
                        ),
                        'from_us' => array(
                            'method' => array(
                                '08', // Worldwide Expedited
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
            )
        );

        if (!isset($codes[$type])) {
            return false;
        } elseif (''===$code) {
            return $codes[$type];
        }

        if (!isset($codes[$type][$code])) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return $codes[$type][$code];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

UPS (now?) has an appendix to the RATING API that does list the codes and descriptions under the `service codes` topic.

[Rating appendix](https://developer.ups.com/api/reference/rating/appendix?loc=en_NL#tabs_1_tabPane_7)

Sample for `Shipments originating in United States` context:

| Description | Shipping | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UPS Standard | 11 | 11 |
| UPS Worldwide Express | 07 | 07 |
| UPS Worldwide Expedited | 08 | 08 |
| UPS Worldwide Express Plus | 54 | 54 |
| UPS Worldwide Saver | 65 | 65 |